# Reconnect a timed-out session

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

When I do an ssh connection, after a while, the connection time-out and my term freeze.

I know Enter + ~ + . to unfreeze it.
But is there another key sequence to reconnect instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following to your `~/.ssh/config file`:

```
Host *
  ServerAliveInterval 60
```

This will make the client send a signal to the server every minute to tell it that it is alive, so the server won't close the connection.